# how to store java date type to mysql date type?

Tags: java, mysql

how to store  java date type to mysql date type?

Answer (score 2):

See that your `Date` is a `java.sql.Timestamp` (especially if you want hours,mins,sec.. to be persisted)
You could convert a `java.util.Date` to a `Timestamp` like so: `new Timestamp(date.getTime())`

Answer (score 0):

Use some instance of the [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to convert the date to a string and use the string in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to execute the SQL statement, like this:

```
Date date = ...;

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (this, that, datecol) values (?, ?, ?)");

ps.setString(1, "hello");
ps.setString(2, "world");
ps.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));

ps.executeUpdate();
```

When you do it like this, you let the JDBC driver convert it to the format that the database expects, so that your program can remain database independent (you don't need to deal with formatting it in the way that MySQL expects it yourself).

When querying the database, also use `PreparedStatement` and use the `getTimestamp()` method on the `ResultSet` to get the date as a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

The `DATE` type in MySQL represents a date only, without time of day and without time zone.

So use `LocalDate` with a driver compliant with JDBC 4.2.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;

myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , today ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```